# hyperlink to retrieve data from a database

Tags: php, mysql, database, hyperlink

I have created a webpage using html/php which contains a form to collect informtaion which I am storing in a mysql database, each record in the database has the date stored automatically, I want to be able to retrieve this information from the database and display is on the webpage as a list of the dates and then I want to make each date a hyperlink so that when click it will show all the data stored in that form on that specific date.

so far I have been able to retrieve the list of the dates using the following (this works as i need it to) :

```
$query="SELECT Date FROM form";
$result=mysql_query($Query,$db);

while ($dbRow=mysql_fetch_array($Result)) 
 {
  $theDate=$dbRow["Date"];
  echo "$theDate<br>";
 }
```

I can not figure out at all how to make each of these dates into a hyperlink... any advice anyone?? thanks!

Comment: echo the html for a hyperlink

Answer (score 3):

**NOTICE** do **NOT** use `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated in PHP 5.5 and may be removed from future versions of PHP. Instead, consider the [alternative MySQL database interfaces](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing) available in PHP like [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli), which are more **feature-rich** and **well-maintained**.

You need to `echo` out all the HTML you want.

```
$query = "SELECT Date FROM form";
$result = mysql_query($Query,$db);

while ($dbRow = mysql_fetch_array($Result)) 
{
    $theDate = $dbRow["Date"];
    echo "<a href='showDateInfo.php?date=$theDate'>$theDate</a><br>";
}
```

I suggest reading up on PHP and HTML basics

Comment: You shouldn't be recommending the use of `ext/mysql`

Comment: thank you, I think I am getting there, I am very new to this.  what would need to be included in the showDateInfo.php page, or should that be the name of the php page I have that code on? I'm a little confused, thanks again

Comment: The showDateInfo.php will be the page that displays all of your date information from the database (i used a generic name). You can use `$_GET['date']` to retrieve the passed date and then query for the information.